# Core Data & TableView & PDFView: How does it all come together?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, core-data

For my current project, I'd like to implement a user interface that's really similar to the Apple Preview application - a list of PDF files on the left hand side and a large UI section to the right that displays the currently selected document:

[image: Preview screenshot]
(Ideally, the file list to the left would display thumbnails instead of filenames, but that's for later.)

*Concerning my background, I have substantial experience in C++ and Qt, but I'm a complete newbie in Objective C and XCode. I am working under Mac OS X 10.8.5 with XCode 5.1.1 (which is the latest on Mountain Lion).*

I have set up an XCode project that brought in the usual [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) elements ([NSPersistentStoreCoordinator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class), [NSManagedObjectModel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class) and [NSManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class)) and I added and wired up the file list and PDF view myself:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel         *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext       *managedObjectContext;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSScrollView *fileList;
@property (weak) IBOutlet PDFView      *pdfView;

(IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

The UI element that diplays the file list is actually an [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class) with one column only and with no headers. (Not sure if the `fileList` property should really be an [NSScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class), but that seemed to be the only option in the pop over when adding the outlet.)

What I have achieved so far is the following:

1. Display a PDF document (with hardcoded path) in the PDF view with code like

   ```
   NSString    *path   = @"/POSIX/path/to/sample/PDF/document.pdf";
   NSURL       *url    = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
   PDFDocument *pdfDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL: url];
   self.pdfView.document = pdfDoc;
   ```
2. Set up my Core Data model: The most relevant entity in there is a `Document` that has a `filename` attribute. I imagine the table view should display a list of those.
3. I also generated [NSManagedObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class) subclasses for every entity in the data model, but I don't use them yet because I don't know what to do with them :o)
4. Scan a (hardcoded) working folder for PDF documents, filter by my predicate and fill (or update) my Core Data model with their filenames - even with only a single fetch request :-). The data is automatically persisted in `~/Library/Application Support/<organization>.<application>/<application>.storedata`.

(At the moment, most of this functionality is bundled in the `[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching]` method.)

So right now, I feel I have most of the required functionality in place, I just don't see the bigger picture of how this all plays together.

**My questions:**

1. How do I make the table view display the list of files stored in my Core Data model ?
   Currently, the app delegate is set to be the table view data source and delegate, so from my understanding, it has to implement some "data source protocol" (?!?) (and a "[protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)" seems to be something like an interface, only without a class to bundle them ?!?)
2. How do I make the PDF view display the document selected in the file list ?
   I have a feeling some instance (the app delegate ?) needs to be notified that the user selected a different file and then make the PDF view display that file...
3. How would an [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class) come into play here ?
   I presume it can also serve as table view data source, only it is notified if anything changes in the Core Data model and can thus update the table view automatically if e.g. a file in the list goes away ?!?

As you can probably tell, I have only a limited understanding of delegates, protocols, etc. so I'd appreciate if someone could clue me in on what the major players are and who is connected to whom and gets notified or updates or whatever.

I have obviously done the due dilligence online and, apart from the official Apple documentation, these pages were especially helpful:

- http://www.objc.io/issue-4/full-core-data-application.html
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone-core-data--mobile-752

but most online resources (including SO) nowadays focus on iOS or, lately, Swift and while I am aware that there are many similarities, I don't have any storyboards, master/detail view controllers or segues and all these just add to my confusion.

I feel I'm really close. Can someone please help me out here ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach of many possible. Create subclasses of `NSViewController` to manage each section of your main view.  One of my applications, for example, has a class to look after a similar list:

```
@interface SongsController : NSViewController <NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate, NSDraggingSource>
```

I create an instance of that inside my `MainMenu.xib` and connect it as a strong property of my application delegate.  It has its own .xib for designing its details.  Then in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`  there's code:

```
[self.mainView addSubview:[self.songsController view]];
```

(`mainView` is a placeholder sub-view of a split view inside my primary `NSWindow`.  I like `NSSplitView` because I usually want sections to be adjustable.)  That lets me move anything to do with list management out of the application delegate.

I tend to move my data handling pieces off into their own classes, a singleton that handles all the CoreData stuff and another that provides the data model by applying "business logic" to the CoreData information.

My data model in this case is not using `NSFetchedResultsController` because I have a lot of filters on what may be shown in the list, so doing my own fetches for refreshing seemed simpler.

That means that selecting a different item in the list comes down to:

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSTableView *view = [aNotification object];
    NSInteger row = [view selectedRow];
    Song *s = [DATA_MODEL songAtRow:row];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:mSongChanged object:s];
}
```

The right hand side of the main view is constructed and connected somewhat the same.  It listens for that `mSongChanged` notification and updates what it's displaying when one arrives.

This doesn't answer all your questions but maybe it'll get you to a less cluttered structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :-) I appreciate your input, but it seems there's already quite a bit of optimization taking place. For the moment, I don't mind e.g. stuffing more functionality into the app delegate and using a single .xib file only. Once I've figured out how this all works, I can still refactor things out into their own classes. And my main view is a split view - for the very same reasons you mention...

Comment: @ssc You really shouldn't put more stuff into the App Delegate. The structure described by Phillip is very much standard on both OS X/iOS (creating a separate `*ViewController` subclass for each task). I disagree about not using `NSFetchedResultsController`, but you should try and folllow the suggestions in this answer - it will certainly help your understanding in the long run.